# I get the same graph on each row when I try to insert a sparkline...how do I get the correct graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create a table that has some data and then a graph on the last (right-most) column. I have:

```
var columns = ['Fruit', 'Color']

var graphData = [
  [6,3,3,2,5],
  [18,7,6,1,0] 
];

var data = [
    [6,3],
    ['Apple', 'Red']
]

// create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");
var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");
thead.selectAll("th").data(columns).enter().append("th").text(function(d) {
        return d;
});
var tbody = table.append("tbody");
var trows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data).enter().append("tr");
var tcells = trows.selectAll("td").data(function(d, i) { return d; })
    .enter().append("td").text(function(d, i) { return d; });
// update (add a column with graphs)
thead.append("th").text('Graphs');
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d) {return [graphData[0]];})
     .enter().append("td").attr("class", "graph").each(lines); 

// a sparklines plot
function lines(test) {  
    var width = 100, height = 20; 
    var data = []
    for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        data[i] = {
            'x': i,
            'y': +test[i]
        }
    }
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width - 10])
        .domain([0,5]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0,10]);
    var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {return x(d.x)})
                .y(function(d) {return y(d.y)});

    d3.select(this).append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
         .append('path')
            .attr('class','line')
            .datum(data)
            .attr('d', line);

}
```

Each row of graphData represent data for a sparkline chart but I can only seem to repeat the first row in my table...eg [6,3,3,2,5]. The second sparkline chart should be from the data [18,7,6,1,0]. How do I  correctly render this? (In the end I will have a table with many more rows than 2).

[My fiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/11/)

Comment: In addition to @LarsKotthoff's answer, you can also simplify the `lines` function; the extra data pre-processing is not necessary:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/13/

Comment: @Mark: Good suggestion....thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your nested selection, you're always returning the same element of `graphData`, regardless of the row:

```
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d) {return [graphData[0]];})
```

You need to return the element corresponding to the row:

```
trows.selectAll("td.graph").data(function(d, i) {return [graphData[i]];})
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgq6ct9f/12/).